# SQL can't update few rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with my update query. I need to change notify_admin from 0 to 1 only for last users row if `action_type = abuse`. (Result should be rows with id=9 and id=13)

I'm trying something like that:

```
UPDATE user_log SET notify_admin = 1 
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM (SELECT user_id FROM user_log) as UNIKALNE
) AND action_type LIKE 'abuse'
```

Unfortunately it update only 1 row (id=3).

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_log` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `action_type` enum('login','logout','abuse') CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL, 
  `notify_admin` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
  `saved` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=15; 

INSERT INTO `user_log` (`id`, `user_id`, `action_type`, `notify_admin`,  `saved`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'login', 0, '2015-11-02 12:13:14'), 
(2, 1, 'logout', 0, '2015-11-02 13:12:11'),
(3, 1, 'abuse', 0, '2016-01-03 14:10:02'), 
(4, 2, 'abuse', 0, '2016-01-04 17:47:03'), 
(5, 2, 'login', 0, '2016-01-04 18:11:55'), 
(6, 1, 'abuse', 0, '2016-01-04 18:23:57'), 
(7, 1, 'abuse', 0, '2016-01-04 18:24:23'), 
(8, 2, 'logout', 0, '2016-01-04 18:25:24'),
(9, 1, 'abuse', 0, '2016-01-04 18:25:32'), 
(10, 1, 'login', 0, '2016-01-05 21:02:59'), 
(11, 3, 'login', 0, '2016-01-05 21:28:43'), 
(12, 3, 'logout', 0, '2016-01-05 21:52:01'),
(13, 2, 'abuse', 0, '2016-01-05 22:00:35'), 
(14, 1, 'logout', 0, '2016-01-05 22:12:09');
```

Comment: You are selecting distinct user ID

`SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM (SELECT user_id FROM user_log) as 
UNIKALNE)`

So only one row with user_id one will be selected and it is id=3

Comment: What should the data set look like afterwards

Comment: it should change notify_admin to 1 only for rows with id 9 and 13 (because there action_type = abuse and it's last occur user with id=1 and user with id=2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first get the most recent `saved` value per user and then update the column.

```
UPDATE user_log 
JOIN 
(
  select id from user_log JOIN (
    select user_id,max(saved) max_saved
    from user_log
    where action_type="abuse"
    group by user_id
  ) t
  ON t.user_id = user_log.user_id AND t.max_saved = user_log.saved
) t2
ON user_log.id = t2.id
SET notify_admin = 1
```

Comment: This will flag _every_ latest user record having abuse, not only if it be the latest one of all records.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen maybe I am missing something here. I think the query is working fine. Would you mind taking a look at the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a07e1c/1

Comment: @AzizShaikh I overthought the question, possibly due to a bad description.  I thought he only wanted to flag abuse records if they are the latest record for a given user.  He wants _latest_ abuse records flagged, which your query covers.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ah, got it. thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are checking User_id from table with distinct so it will give 1,2,3 only and then comparing with abuse action type so it will update row 3 which matches.

replace `User_id` with `id` if you want to update for all rows

```
UPDATE user_log SET notify_admin = 1 WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM (SELECT id FROM user_log) as UNIKALNE) AND action_type LIKE 'abuse'
```

Comment: I have tried that but it change all occur where action_type = 'abuse' but I need only last 2 (for id=9 and id=13)

Comment: if you want for id 9,13 then there is only unique field is `id` Add id in (9,13)

Comment: Yes but it should update dynamically so the reason why it should update only rows with id 9 and 13 is, this rows are LAST occur for this user rows with action_type = 'abuse'

Comment: `UPDATE user_log SET notify_admin = 1 where id in
(select TOP 2 id from user_log WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM (SELECT id FROM user_log) as UNIKALNE) AND action_type LIKE 'abuse' order by id desc)` Try this. it may help